# Unable to start tomcat service 9.0.48, keep throwing "PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have .."

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I've just updated my tomcat to `9.0.48` but it always fails to start.

I tried everything, removed pid file, disabled/enabled service, stop tomcat,.... but unable to start. It keeps throwing this error from my truncated `journalctl -xe` output :

> PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current
> user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted

=>>

```
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm startup.sh[63077]: Existing PID file found during start.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm startup.sh[63077]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm startup.sh[63077]: Tomcat started.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm shutdown.sh[63089]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm polkitd[841]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:63063:8684558 (system bus name :1.714, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jun 15 21:07:55 infra-vm sudo[63061]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

This my service unit :

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64

#Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/updated/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/updated/temp/catalina.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/updated/
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/updated/
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/updated/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/updated/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Why is the service doing a `shutdown` after every startup? As you can see in the above error, I run the start service command but get a shutdown error.

If I comment out or remove the  `ExecStop` from the systemd tomcat unit file, the start doesn't raise error anymore, but remains inactive (from `sytemctl status tomcat`)

I've seen the error has been reported here many times, but no suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

It was `JAVA_HOME` misconfiguration in tomcat unit service, cause I also updated java version on the lic server, but gave an obsolete jre path

Found it by testing tomcat startup srcipt manually, so I update the service unit  by changing line

> Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64

to

> Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64"

and everything is working fine now.